# Get User ids of all members of multiple queues

Tags: apex, soql

In my org we have few queues with name like salesA, salesB...
And i was trying to get all members (ids) of these salesqueue

```
List<Group> Salesqueues =  [SELECT Id, name FROM Group WHERE type='Queue' and Name like '%Sales%'];Map<Id,GroupMember> Salesmembers = new Map<Id,GroupMember>(); 
for(GroupMember sgm : [SELECT Group.Name, UserOrGroupId FROM GroupMember WHERE GroupId IN:Salesqueues.Id ])
{
  Salesmembers.put(sgm.UserOrGroupId,sgm);
}
```

but i got error in for loop line :  `Error: Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: List<Group>`

So i think i need to loop through Salesqueues.Id one by and inside that for  loop get its members using SOQL. But this is wrong approach and i might hit the SOQL Limit, so what would be the best approach to get all queuemebers id's where queue name contains 'Sales'

Thanks a lot for suggestions:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is here: `IN:Salesqueues.Id`. Salesqueues is a collection of Group sObjects and you need a collection of Id's insted. Try the following:

```
Map<Id,Group> Salesqueues = new Map<Id,Group> ([SELECT Id, name FROM Group WHERE type='Queue' and Name like '%Sales%']);
Map<Id,GroupMember> Salesmembers = new Map<Id,GroupMember>(); 

for(GroupMember sgm : [SELECT Group.Name, UserOrGroupId FROM GroupMember WHERE GroupId IN:Salesqueues.keySet() ])
{
    Salesmembers.put(sgm.UserOrGroupId,sgm);
}
```

Comment: Actually `IN :salesQueues` works just fine when it's a `List`.

Comment: Interesting, in this many years I've always thought only a collection of ID's works with the `IN` clause...

Comment: Thanks guys for reply: I did like this :- List<ID> SalesqueueIds = new List<ID>();
        for (Group g : [SELECT Id FROM Group WHERE type='Queue' and Name like '%Sales%']){       
             SalesqueueIds.add(g.Id);
        }                                                                                                                                                             And then i used SalesqueueIds for IN clause.